# Bug or what? - Empty result of SELECT only when bigger LIMIT in MySQL 8.0.16+

Tags: mysql

This query without LIMIT or with LIMIT 100+ return empty result, but with LIMIT 1 result exists:

```sql
SELECT id
FROM tbl_test_bug
WHERE col_1 = 1 AND col_2 = 1
#LIMIT 1 -- That work
```

Also works without specifying LIMIT if dropping index "col_1_idx".

Tested in MySQL 8.0.16+.

Source data for playback:

```sql
-- Create table
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl_test_bug;
CREATE TABLE tbl_test_bug (
  id int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  col_1 TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  col_2 TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id DESC),
  KEY col_1_idx (col_1),
  KEY col_2_idx (col_2)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

-- Filling the table with random data (800 rows)
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE gen_rows_test()
BEGIN
  DECLARE idx INT DEFAULT 800;
  WHILE idx > 0 DO
    INSERT INTO tbl_test_bug (col_1, col_2) VALUES (FLOOR(1 + (RAND() * 2)), FLOOR(1 + (RAND() * 10)));
    SET idx = idx - 1;
  END WHILE;
END;;
CALL gen_rows_test();;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS gen_rows_test;;
```

[image: Bug screenshot]

Comment: Reproduced. https://dbfiddle.uk/9JsRaJfI Report as a bug.

Comment: It may be a bug, but I don't use procedure. After creating tables and data, it is correct to use select data.

Comment: It's not about the procedure. The problem was found on a real high-load site with a different table, without procedures. I just made it easier to reproduce it.

Comment: There's seemingly a bogus index and `LIMIT` clause probably makes query optimiser skip it.

Comment: In a real production table, a LIMIT of more than 2 already returns empty results (there are ~30 thousand rows).

Comment: Bugs can be reported here: https://bugs.mysql.com/

Comment: Ok, made a bug report https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=111659

Comment: @Oleg, put that bug report in an answer and return here in a year or so to update when it’s fixed!